# how to find rowsize in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

One of my DBs have grown closer to permitted size.

Inorder to find out the table containing the max data, i used the following query:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' exec sp_spaceused '?'"
```

It returned the culprit table comprising the max data.

As a next step, i want to cleanup the rows based on the size. For this, i would like to order the rows based on size.

How to achieve this using a query? Are there any tools to do this?

Answer (score 11):

This will give you a list of rows by size, just set @table and @idcol accordingly (as written it'll run against the Northwind sample)

```
declare @table varchar(20)
declare @idcol varchar(10)
declare @sql varchar(1000)

set @table = 'Employees'
set @idcol = 'EmployeeId'
set @sql = 'select ' + @idcol +' , (0'

select @sql = @sql + ' + isnull(datalength(' + name + '), 1)' 
    from syscolumns where id = object_id(@table)
set @sql = @sql + ') as rowsize from ' + @table + ' order by rowsize desc'

exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach for all table sizes is to use the stored procedure at [this site](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/121/determing-sql-server-table-size.aspx).
You could alter the select statement of that stored procedure to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #TempTable
Order by dataSize desc
```

to have it ordered by size.

How do you want to cleanup? Cleanup the biggest row of a specific table? Not sure I understand the question.

**EDIT** (response to comment)

Assuming your eventlog has the same layout as mine (DNN eventlog):

```
SELECT     LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), LogProperties)) AS length
FROM         EventLog
ORDER BY length DESC
```

Comment: Exactly. The table in question is EventLog table. I certainly don't want to delete all the rows, but the ones in descending order of size.

Comment: note this query will not work in sql 2000, probably best using datalength

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this to get the size of the indexes and keys: (edit:sorry for wall of text, cant get the format to work)

```
WITH table_space_usage
( schema_name, table_name, index_name, used, reserved, ind_rows, tbl_rows )
AS (
SELECT s.Name
     , o.Name
     , coalesce(i.Name, 'HEAP')
     , p.used_page_count * 8
     , p.reserved_page_count * 8
     , p.row_count
     , case when i.index_id in ( 0, 1 ) then p.row_count else 0 end
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats p
  INNER JOIN sys.objects as o
    ON o.object_id = p.object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas as s
    ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.indexes as i
    on i.object_id = p.object_id and i.index_id = p.index_id
 WHERE o.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
   and o.is_ms_shipped = 0
)
 SELECT t.schema_name
     , t.table_name
     , t.index_name
     , sum(t.used) as used_in_kb
     , sum(t.reserved) as reserved_in_kb
     , case grouping(t.index_name) 
    when 0 then sum(t.ind_rows) 
    else sum(t.tbl_rows) end as rows
 FROM table_space_usage as t
 GROUP BY
       t.schema_name
     , t.table_name
     , t.index_name
 WITH ROLLUP
 ORDER BY
      grouping(t.schema_name)
    , t.schema_name
    , grouping(t.table_name)
    , t.table_name
    , grouping(t.index_name)
    , t.index_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work

```
delete table where id in 
(
    select top 100 id
    from table
    order by datalength(event_text) + length(varchar_column) desc
)
```

(since you are dealing with an event table its probably a text column you are looking at ordering on so the datalength sql command is key here)

Comment: delete table? is it a joke?