# Calculating the length of each record in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find rowsize in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114728/how-to-find-rowsize-in-table)

how to calculate the length of each record in the table (Sql Server 2008)

Comment: What do you mean by `record`? Whole row? Including internal overhead? Also please provide your table definition. If it doesn't include potentially off row columns there is an easy way.

Comment: I mean record as a tuple or row

Comment: CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
 RollID INT,
 Name NVARCHAR(100),
 Class NVARCHAR(100)
)

Comment: Ah actually the way I was thinking of doesn't work. I thought this could be a use for `%%rowdump%%` but looks like that doesn't actually give the whole row.

Comment: Hi martin.. I looking to find the variable row size.. as that could help me to track the update changes in that row.. or to find whether the row is modified

Answer (score 2):

Try `LEN()` instead of `DATALENGTH()`

```
SELECT LEN(yourcolumnName) AS LengthOfEntry From yourtablename
```

This gives you the length of each entry in that column

Just string them together for every column to get entries for entire table

Example:

```
SELECT LEN(yourcolumnName) as Column1, LEN(yourcolumnname2) AS Column2 From yourtablename
```

You can use `SUM()` to get the total of every character in that column

```
SELECT SUM(LEN(yourcolumnName)) as Column1, SUM(LEN(yourcolumnname2)) AS Column2 From yourtablename
```

Comment: He's looking for the total row size; this is only for a single column.

Comment: DATALENGTH will not give you the exact length ... for INT the length is always 2 despite the changes in value .. I want to use this length to detect changes in a row

Comment: This is true, I will leave answer since I am curious about this. When doing varchars dividing by 2 gives you the exact length of that row. I cannot experiment with Ints right now, where else would this type of solution cause a problem?

Comment: I guess the object types varchar , nvarchar are noticeable of changes

Comment: @user824910 maybe LEN() is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks harper, that solves the previos issue we had with the DATALENGTH, Is there any way to find the size of the row so that i can understand the changes to the current row on comparing the back up  replicated row in repicated database i have?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by row size? I am taking it to mean a total of all the lengths in that row? I added a query that pulls the total length of the column, it may be of some help to you. I am unsure how to do rows.

Answer (score 0):

> as that could help me to track the update changes in that row.. or to
>   find whether the row is modified

You are looking for Triggers, I think. This will help you in ascertaining the changes made in any record..

[Triggers Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)