# T-SQL Estimate max row size of a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, row

How do you estimate the max row size of a `VIEW` im MS SQL Server? Is there a stored procedure to do this or it must be done manually? I know that it usually should not be a concern, but I need it for an application that imposes restrictions on data rows acquired from the SQL Server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find rowsize in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114728/how-to-find-rowsize-in-table)

Comment: No, I want to have precisely the maximum row size, not the actual row size. That means that the view does not even have to have data in it.

Comment: I think you can use the `text in row` option for the system stored procedure `sp_tableoption` to restrict the amount of data in the rows. Please find [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms189087(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: As mentioned above I need this info for a view, and not for a table.